# 99% confidence interval, proportion

Tags: r, intervals

Maybe a dumb question, but I just started, so thanks for any help.

I created 99% confidence interval for a proportion, but I'm not sure if it is correct, how can I make sure, (when we're calculating confidence interval for mean, we're using t-score, and we can test the results by using t.test function and degrees of freedom)

Is there any similar function to do the same thing for z, proportions? or I can do the same thing by using t.test?

Comment: This belongs on stats.stackexchange.com. Can you provide more information about your proportions? What are the numerator and denominator? Are those, e.g., counts?

Comment: I am not sure about my result i.e. the interval itself, how can I check if it has worked properly?

Comment: Proportions generally don't follow the normal distribution. Using an approach that relies on the normal distribution is inferior to available approaches for proportions. You have not answered my request for clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of [functions in R for computing confidence intervals for proportions](http://www.modernstatisticswithr.com/modchapter.html#confprop). Personally, I like to use the `binomCI` function from the `MKinfer` package:

```
install.packages("MKinfer")
library(MKinfer)
x <- 50 # The number of "successes" in your data
n <- 100 # The number of observations in your data
binomCI(x, n, conf.level = 0.99, method = "wald")
```

Note however that the so-called Wald interval (which is presented in most introductory texts on statistics) that you probably computed usually is a poor choice. See [this link](http://www.modernstatisticswithr.com/modchapter.html#confprop) for some other alternatives available through `binomCI`.